# How can i access the templates of controls and modify them in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Where and how do i look for to access the default templates of say for e.g a checkbox, so that i can modify few styles in it.

Answer (score 0):

http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/firstnetctrl.htm

That explains how to do what you are trying to do.